# Invoke issue when the bloomberg API is connecting to BBCOM via C#

Tags: c#, error-handling, invoke, bloomberg

I am working on C# with VS. I downloaded the code example of bloomberg API.

When I run this :

```
        string serverHost = "127.0.0.1";
        int serverPort = 8194;

        SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions();
        sessionOptions.ServerHost = serverHost;
        sessionOptions.ServerPort = serverPort;

        System.Console.WriteLine("Connecting to " + serverHost + ":" + serverPort);
        Session session = new Session(sessionOptions);
        bool sessionStarted = session.Start();
        if (!sessionStarted)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Failed to start session.");
            return;
        }
```

I com¨me to the break mode and I have the following error:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' : 'A call to
>   PInvoke function
>   'Bloomberglp.Blpapi!Bloomberglp.Blpapi.Internal.DapiSupAdapter::blpdapisup_startBbcomm'
>   has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke
>   signature does not match the unmanaged

I don't really get what it means

Comment: pInvokeStackImbalance is a managed debugging assistant so you probably have DLL import wrong

Answer (score 1):

had same issue - for me it was the the build settings "prefer 32-bit" - uncheck that , so that it builds 64-bit